# How to upgrade snap installed Android Studio to version "patch 2"?

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, snap

I have a lab with 32 linux machines, with Android Studio installed using snap.

The version instaled (last version) is Bumblebee patch 1 (built 1 february 2022).

This version has a small bug when defining size of elements in screens.

If you install Android Studio "directly" (no snap), the last one is version patch 2 (built 17 february 2022). This version doesn't have the bug.

When I run "check updates" inside Android Studio, he says "No ide or plugin updates available".

When I run the command "sudo snap refresh --list", he says something like "all snaps are updated".

So the question is: Is there anyway that I can "manually upgrade" Android Studio, not depending on availability of this upgrade in the snap system, although it was installed via snap ?